# How do Airbnb implemented localization and realtime booking?

Tags: geolocation, shopify, real-time, real-time-updates, airbnb-js-styleguide

I was wondering if anyone know about how did the Airbnb implemented their system such that only local listings or listings within a specific area (based on the postal code) will appear to the user ? And also , how did they implemented real time booking so that if a property gets booked , it won't appear available to the next person ? Are there any API's available that could help me implement the same for my store ?

If anyone could provide any guidance , that will be very helpful.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

AirBNB don't use Shopify.

It's an entirely different system. With that, they'll have very different technical abilities.